# Color of field Error in VFP

Tags: slds, inputfield, styleclass

I am using the Standard field Email of the Standard object Contact in a VFP. In Salesforce when I enter an invalid email address, I get the error message like this [image]

However When I enter an invalid email in the VFP, the error displayed is like this [image]

Here is the line from VFP

```
<apex:inputField style="width:150px;" id="ContactEmail" html-maxlength="40" styleClass="slds-input inputHalf reqInput contact-email" value="{!wrapperRecord.contactrecord.Email}" />
```

When I replace the above line with

```
<apex:column headerValue="Email">
                <apex:inputField value="{!eachRecord.record.Email}" required="true"/>
</apex:column>
```

I see the error message like this

[image]

My question is - 
why isn't the Field Error on VFP with SLDS style displayed in Red? 
How can i change the color from Black to Red.